# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Salaamun Alekum 
I Am Getting NULL in `file` instance of action after posting a file in FORM

```
 public ActionResult CreateDoctorProfile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            int LoggedInPersonID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoggedInPersonId"]);
            erx_t_personnel PersonnelInformation = db.erx_t_personnel.Where(PersonnelInformation1 => PersonnelInformation1.Person_Id == LoggedInPersonID).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(PersonnelInformation);
        }
```

This Is My View

```
@model Doctors_Search_Engine.Models.erx_t_personnel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Personnel Registration";


}

<h2>Personnel Registration</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

What Should I Do To Get Value In `file` Of Action Parameters. I Need Guidance On This

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The problem you have and the subject of your question are totally different. It's confusing.*

If you are having an issue passing the file to your controller then your input file name should match the parameter in your controller method.
Change `<input type="file" name="Image" /> to <input type="file" name="file" />`

Or change your action result to:

```
public ActionResult CreateDoctorProfile(HttpPostedFileBase Image){}
```

You also need to set the encryption type to your form.

```
using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: Salaam Thank You But No @Moe Its Still Not Working

Comment: I Also Tried To Give `name=file` In My CSHTML

Comment: I Am Getting `null` In `HttpPostedFileBase file` In Action Parameter